# Abort heredoc command if a subshell returns an error?

Tags: bash, heredoc

```
set -u
cat <<EOF
$FOO
bar
EOF
```

Prints: `-bash: FOO: unbound variable` and returns 1. This is what I want. 
BUT this:

```
set -u
foo() { echo $FOO; }
cat <<EOF
$(foo)
bar
EOF
```

Prints:

```
-bash: FOO: unbound variable

bar
```

and returns 0.

I am looking for a good way to make the latter snippet behave the same way as the former. 
Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
From the answers I got so far, I think, I need to clarify the use case a little bit, because the example above is a bit of a simplification.

What I am after is kind of primitive "template processing". 
There is a common template, with some "configurable parts", e.g.:

```
cat user.json
{
    "id": "$USER_ID",
    "name": "$USER_NAME",
    "roles": "$(ROLES director)", 
}
```

Then there are some inputs:

```
cat peter.sh
USER_ID=foo
USER_NAME=peter
ROLES() { cat ${1}_roles.text | grep $USER_ID }
```

And then the "template processor" does something like this:

```
. peter.sh
set -u
contents="$(<user.json)"
eval "cat <<EOF
$contents
EOF
"
```

The is that *both* variables and functions are external to the processor, it does not know what they are, so
(1) I can't evaluate all functions before the heredoc is actually executed, because I don't know what they are (and what to do with them), and
(2) I can't do things like `$(foo) && bar || $FOO_UNKNOWN` as @suspectus suggested, because `bar` here has to be the rest of the template.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Just noticing: shouldn't your second example's `echo $FOO` be `$FOO`?

Comment: What's reason of calling `eval`?

Comment: @anubhava to get the variables/functions expanded

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to behave *exactly* the same? Just an additional error output-:

```
set -u
foo() { $FOO; }
cat <<EOF
$(foo) && bar || $FOO_UNKNOWN
EOF
```

Comment: A [here-doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is only subject to   parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. The lines aren't interpreted as a whole, so I don't think this would work.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer with a more complete description of the actual use case, which I don't think is helped by this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

A possible *workaround* can be to call function before here-doc and let it exit if there is an unbound variable:

```
foo() { echo "$FOO"; }

set -u
var="$(foo)" || exit 1
cat <<-EOF
$var
bar
EOF
```

**Output:**

```
FOO: unbound variable
```

with exit status as `1`

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer with a more complete description of the actual use case, which I don't think is helped by this unfortunately.